# Custom language definition files in Xcode 4 (pbfilespec pblangspec)

Tags: xcode, actionscript-3, actionscript, xcode4, syntax-highlighting

How (where?) do you install custom language definition files in Xcode4? Tried to put them in a lot of places without any luck.

Typically this is for Actionscript 3 syntax highlighting files that were workin in Xcode 3 (
https://github.com/iloveitaly/Xcode-Actionscript-Language-Specification ).